# How to disable auto translation in MS Access when exporting to CSV?

Tags: csv, ms-access, export, translation

I am exporting a MS Access query to a CSV file and running into a strange issue where it is automatically trying to translate a cell's value to another language.  It adds a lot of text that breaks the CSV formatting and results in an invalid file.

Example output (ignore bad translations please):

```
"activity_title_en","activity_title_es"
"Appointment","El Appointment"
"Court Date","Court Date

Source Language

Target Language
Court Date
Human Translation
Translate
Fecha de corte
```

It should be

```
"activity_title_en","activity_title_es"
"Appointment","El Appointment"
"Court Date","Court Date"
```

How can I disable this?  Nothing in the Access options suggests that this will occur.

Comment: Not a feature in MS Access. Do you happen to use some sort of translation tool? Are you using VBA code to export to csv? Are you using an export specification?

Comment: It is apparent that the expected output has strings from more than one language.  Does this mean the database is setup with tables and columns that contain multiple languages?  Could it be that the query on which the data is based is pulling more data fields than expected?  The question doesn't contain the query SQL statement, nor whether or not the query returns the expected data when viewed as a default datasheet in Access.

Comment: I managed to find a workaround after a lot of investigation.  The column in the table that the query was pulling from was called "ContactTypeSpanish".  If I rename the column to something else, e.g. "ContactType_es", then the weird translation behavior disappears.  Changing it back to "ContactTypeSpanish" causes the behavior to return.

To test if there was something weird installed on Windows I moved the DB onto a clean machine (just out of the box) and the behaviour occurred there too, so it seems to just be something Access did.  Surreal.  Thanks for the comments though.

Comment: Weird.  For curiosities sake, how did you view the CSV files after creating them?  Did you view the raw text version (in Notepad), or does it open in Excel, for example?  This doesn't explain the behavior, but I'd really like to know if it is Access for sure or another application.  I would actually guess that Excel or Word (other office apps) to do something like this before I would attribute it to Access.

Comment: I viewed it in Notepad.  However, that wasn't even necessary.  When working through the External Data dialogs to export it, Access shows you a preview of what it'll look like - that preview also had the weird translation text in it, so it was definitely Access doing it.  I wish I knew how to turn it off, but for now the workaround is sufficient and I can't bring myself to throw more hours at it...